# Is there a way to entirely remove the Messages app from an iOS 12 device?

Tags: ios, parental-controls

I'm trying to set up an iPad for a child and don't want any Messages app at all. Apple seems to want to keep it there. Any way to completely remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 12 does not seem to allow Messages to be turned off. But this method should prevent messages from working.

Settings > Content & Privacy Restrictions

And set Account Changes to *Don't Allow* and password protect that setting by turning Content & Privacy Restrictions **on** at the top of that screen. She will not be able to add an account (EG iCloud/AppleID) that would allow iMessage to get messages.

Note that a clever and determined child will often find workarounds to anything and could easily find a web-based messaging service available via Safari.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I'm trying to disable Safari as well.